# Mongoose: Using model or schema provided by a module from npm/node_modules

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have an application that defines a few models and creates the global Mongoose connection (`mongoose.connect(...)`). The app also relies on some models defined by a module in the `node_modules` directory. The problem that I'm running into is that the application and the separate module do not share the same global connection object.

Okay, fine. Rather than having the module export a model it can just export the schema and the main application can register it with the connection. In the app there would be something like:

```
var SomeSchema = require('somemodule').SomeSchema;
mongoose.model('SomeModel', SomeSchema);
```

Unfortunately this isn't working either. When the model is registered, Mongoose is checking whether the given schema is an instance of `mongoose.Schema` ([here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/0b2784f86e95473883ea4bb1484ba58dba3c1e59/lib/index.js#L230)). When `SomeSchema` was defined (in the separate module) it creates the schema with `new mongoose.Schema({ ... })` where `mongoose` is required from the module's local dependency tree. When the application registers the schema it uses the `mongoose` required from the application's dependencies. Since the two copies of mongoose are not the same object the given schema is not an instance of `mongoose.Schema` and an error is thrown.

Do you have any recommendations here? I was thinking one potential solution would be to have the module create a "plugin" function that accepts the schema and adds all the paths, methods, etc. The main app would create an empty schema and add the plugin. Something like:

```
var somePlugin = require('somemodule').somePlugin;
var SomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema();
SomeSchema.plugin(somePlugin);
mongoose.model('SomeModel', SomeSchema);
```

Are there any alternatives?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you really want .? U just have to put all your schemae in different file for project organization ..?

Comment: I want to reuse models provided by an NPM module across multiple projects/apps.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by hacking the prototype of the schema to use the correct instance of `mongoose.Schema` so that it will pass the internal Mongoose `instanceof` check. So for your example, I would add a line like this:

```
var SomeSchema = require('somemodule').SomeSchema;
SomeSchema.__proto__ = mongoose.Schema.prototype;
mongoose.model('SomeModel', SomeSchema);
```

It's certainly not kosher but it works for me!